# TeamCity Code Coverage unexpected results

Tags: c#, unit-testing, teamcity, code-coverage

I have a project set up for CI in TeamCity, and it's showing some odd results for code coverage:

[image]

Note the duplication of the classes.

Looking at one of these classes, the highlighted code as "not covered" is as follows (it's the only code in the class):

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T, long> where T : class
    {
        protected BaseRepository(ISessionManager sessionManager)
        : base(sessionManager)
        {
            //nothing in here.
        }
}
```

so here's the problem: this code *is* covered, but I think because TeamCity is counting it three times and the coverage only once, I'm getting 33% coverage... which is not correct.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here, and how to fix it?

Comment: What coverage engine do you use?

Comment: @OlegRybak the built-in dotCover product.

Comment: do you have 3 instances of each class?

Comment: @SamHolder what would constitute an "instance" of the class in this context?

Comment: there are 3 `BaseRepository<T>` entries in the code coverage report. Do you really have 3 classes called `BaseRepository<T>` in different namespaces in your code?

Comment: @SamHolder no; they are the same class, in the same namespace.  They're just showing up three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem with duplicate test container dll files loaded from multiple locations.

You need to check the `Run tests from` and `Do not run tests from` sections from your test runner configuration and figure out why the dlls are loaded multiple times. In my case it was the `obj` folders, and my `Edit assembly files exclude list` now looks like:

```
**\obj\**\*.dll
```

You got it tripled, so you probably need to figure out even more locations to exclude.

Comment: So this, for me, was a combination of excessively loose wildcards in the assembly inclusion, and different tests using different build configurations.  We cleaned up the paths and patterns to the assemblies, and the problem went away.  Thanks!